# How to calculate the area of ​a figure bounded by 4 equations?

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals, area

I need calculate the area of the shape bounded:
$y=-x^3; \; xy=-16; \; y=0; \; x=-e^2$

I drew a graph and found the intersection points of the functions:
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/757YP.png)

I want to use:
[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k0bq.gif)

Am I doing the next step right?

$S = \int\limits_{-\exp^2}^{-2} -\frac{16}{x}dx + \int\limits_{-2}^{0} -x^3 dx + \int\limits_{0}^{2} -x^3 -(-\frac{16}{x}) dx$

P.S. Okay, if I solve next: $S = \int\limits_{-e^2}^{-2}\left(\frac{-16}{x}\right)dx+\int\limits_{-2}^0(-x^3)dx=(-16 \cdot \ln{e^2} - (-16 \cdot \ln{2})) + (-\frac{-2^4}{4}-(-\frac{0^4}{4}))=-32+16 \cdot \ln{2} - 4=-36+16 \cdot \ln{2}$.

Comment: I am very afraid that I have lost some part of the expression.

Comment: You don't need the third integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to write the following.
$$\int\limits_{-e^2}^{-2}\left(\frac{-16}{x}\right)dx+\int\limits_{-2}^0(-x^3)dx=$$
$$=-16\ln|x||_{-e^2}^{-2}-\frac{x^4}{4}|_{-2}^0=-16\ln2+32+4=36-16\ln2.$$

Comment: In other words, the OP was wrong, because the region does not extend to the half-plane $x>0$.

Comment: @almagest Yes. I got $36-16\ln2$.

Comment: @Student I added something. See now.

Comment: Many thanks. I lost the minus, but when I found it, counted it, and our answers are identical.

Comment: Looks like I'm still not attentive. Your area is valid, and mine is negative.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really about what the description of the region means.

[image]

There clearly is an area in the left halfplane bounded by $x=-e^2$, the two curves, and the $x$-axis. The question is whether anything in the right halfplane should also be included.

Again the two curves and the $x$-axis bound a region, this time below the $x$-axis. If we include it, there is no good reason to stop at $x=e^2$ or at $x=2$ (where the two curves intersect). So should we include it all?

I would say not, because:

(1) it is unusual in this type of question to have the region of interest in two parts;

(2) the area of the part in the right-hand plane has infinite area.

Accordingly, the OP should only use the first two of his integrals.

Having said that, I would comment that the description of the region is not well drafted, it would have been easy to add that the region was in the left half-plane, for example.

Comment: \int\limits_{-e^2}^{-2}\left(\frac{-16}{x}\right)dx+\int\limits_{-2}^0(-x^3)dx ?

Comment: That is, as Michael Rozenberg wrote?

Comment: Yes, his answer is correct - that is why I upvoted it! I just thought it was helpful to put in the graph to show what was going on.

Comment: I edited the question and added a calculation, but I don’t know if it’s right.

Comment: @Student You have got your signs wrong. If you evaluate from $-e^2$ to $-2$ you subtract the value at $-e^2$ from the value at $-2$, not the other way round. Similarly for the integral from -2 to 0. Note that the entire area is above the $x$-axis so it must have a positive area, not a negative one.

Comment: Yes, correct: -16 * ln(2)+32+4=36-16 * ln(2).

Comment: @Student Well done!

Comment: I inattentively rated: −16*ln | x |

Comment: Oh, I need to learn a lot, including attentiveness.

Comment: It’s a pity, I can't upvote your answer, since you explained about cutting off part of the integral.

Comment: You were right to accept Michael Rozenberg's answer. Incidentally, his answers are almost always right!

Comment: Thank you. I will try to achieve a greater reputation, and upvote your answer too.